# What is the difference between the Power Law and Zipf's Law?

Tags: st.statistics

I am new to statistics.  Could somebody tell me what is the difference between a Power Law and Zipf's Law. The latter could be just for texts but I cant see any difference in their essence.

Answer (score 4):

Zipf's law is a special case of power laws, with power -1.  (The harmonic series diverges, so the distribution in Zipf's law is truncated at some point.  But the essential character is the point: the probabilities decline like a power of the argument.)

Answer (score 3):

"Power law" is a way of describing a general class of distributions (functions, really) that show scale invariance and slow decay in tail probabilities.  Zipf's law is a specific (discrete) distribution that falls into the class of power law distributions.